# Do pedal-driven bicycles exist that can handle highway commutes?

Tags: speed, long-distance

Do pedal-driven bi/tricycles exist which can be driven at highway speeds without fuel or electric drive assistance?

Assisted brakes, steering, lights, and amenities such as climate control or navigation are valid addons as long as the drive system is manually operated. Drive assistance must be limited to gearing (and perhaps flywheels.)

Comment: They do exist if you are an Olympic-level athlete.  If you are just a regular guy, gears can't create energy out of thin air.

Comment: In theory one could build a flywheel-assisted unit that would let you "store up" energy by pedaling for several minutes before you began moving.  At best you'd need to pedal about 5 minutes standing still for each minute of highway speeds you achieved.  Beyond that there are are beginning to appear various solar powered cycles that can provide some assistance, but they would not permit sustained highway speeds.

Comment: Adding any extra systems like air conditioning would be extremely counter-productive because they would increase the weight of the vehicle without actually helping to power the vehicle. The batteries or other mechanism required to power air conditioning would add quite a bit of weight to the bike. A large flywheel wouldn't really be feasible because of the huge weight this would add to the bike.  Handling highway commutes would also mean handling hills that occur on highways.  A vehicle that's meant for highway commutes that loses all it's power when you hit an offramp isn't a very good idea.

Comment: _Climate control_? On a bicycle? I'm having a hard time believing that this is a genuine question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

The Tour De France currently has an average speed of about 40km/h, fasted speeds are a team time trial, about 58km/h over 25km. (Wikipedia), average cyclist would be with 1/2 those speeds, average person probably half again. These speeds, while impressive, are well below what I would consider "highway speeds", and the bikes they rode , while expensive enough to expect it as standard equipment rather than optional extra, certainly did not have climate control and power assisted steering

An elite athlete can output about 1000 Watts peak, 700W over 10 minutes, and sustain about 300Watts of power indefinitely.  A normal person half of that*

Climate control in a car requires about 3000W. A small car engine produces about 50000W, a super car engine, 500000W.
The more power you need to go faster climbs exponentially, so a cyclist maintaining say 30km/h needs 10 times the power to go 100km/h (and that seems light to me).

That is presuming all the extras weight nothing and do not increase rolling and aerodynamic losses, but lets argue that those are offset by technology that improves efficiency .

If you want to create a cycle that can cruise at highway speeds, with Climate control and power assisted everything, you will need to create a rider with a power output of about 10kW-20kW. At this time, society will have bigger problems than highway congestion and climate change - like feeding and controlling these 10kW humanoids.

*Actual number may be out by a factor of 10, but  does not change the disccusion.

Also: Note the recent drop in average Tour speed? When did the drug doping scandal happen? I'll let the reader decide.....

Comment: Bear in mind addons are acceptable, but not required.

Comment: Fully enclosed recumbent bikes are more aerodynamic and can therefore probably sustain higher speeds than the bikes used in bicycle racing.  But still not highway-speed except downhill.

Comment: World record for distance covered in 1 hour - regular bicycle: 51 km (Jens Voigt, former professional cyclist). Faired recumbent bike: 91 km (Francesco Russo) http://www.gizmag.com/new-world-record-in-one-hour-cycling/19497/. Neither of these people is a typical bike commuter.  It does show how much of an advantage you get from a faired recumbent bike.

Comment: @Nik Would aftermarket gearing make any difference? I understand the human energy requirement but I'm not familiar with how it translates into reasonable-sized transmissions.

Comment: Gearing is not going to help.  If it takes 500W of power to achieve a given speed on a given bicycle, and a cyclist can only sustain 300W, then gearing cannot change that power output. It can only change the rotational speed, but as rotational speed goes up, torque goes down, so power remains constant.

Comment: @nik: Yep, those are getting up to highways speeds, but the OP expressly required climate control, which (for social reason as well as OP's) would be required for a fully enclosed commuter. :)

Comment: @mattnz - if I understand the original question correctly, he said that he would accept a pedal-powered vehicle even if it had add-ons that were powered by other means such as batteries. He did not insist on having these things, but stated that their presence would not disqualify a proposed solution.